# Why can't I access this.props.navigation in react native Alert?

Tags: react-native, alert, react-navigation

```
Alert.alert(
      '',
      'Kindly Select from the following Actions',
      [
        {
          text: 'Edit',
          onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate(
            'PositionForm',
            {
              formType: 'edit',
              item: this.props.position
            }
          )
        },
        { text: 'Delete', onPress: () => console.log('delete Pressed') },
      ]
    );
```

I am looking for a work around. I want to navigate to another page when an edit button is clicked on alert. I am using react-navigation and redux. Kindly Help.
Thanks in advance.

COmplete Component COde is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

class PositionItem extends Component {
  showAlert() {
    Alert.alert(
      '',
      'Kindly Select from the following Actions',
      [
        {
          text: 'Edit',
          onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate(
            'PositionForm',
            {
              formType: 'edit',
              item: this.props.position
            }
          )
        },
        { text: 'Delete', onPress: () => console.log('delete Pressed') },
      ]
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {
      positionContainer,
      textStyle,
      iconsStyle,
      positionName,
      starIconStyle
    } = styles;
    const {
      name
    } = this.props.position;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showAlert.bind(this)}>
        <View style={positionContainer}>
          <View style={positionName}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{name}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={iconsStyle}>
            <Icon style={starIconStyle} name="star-o" size={30} color="#ccc" />
            <Icon name="angle-right" size={30} color="#ccc" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  positionContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc'
  },
  textStyle: {
    marginBottom: 0,
    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '600',
    borderLeftWidth: 6,
    borderColor: '#cccccc',
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    lineHeight: 20
  },
  iconsStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 20,
  },
  starIconStyle: {
    paddingTop: 2,
    paddingRight: 15
  },
  positionName: {
    flex: 80
  }
});

export default PositionItem;
```

Comment: Can you post the whole component? And is that component used as react-navigation screen component?

Comment: maybe you will have to bind 'this' to Aler.alert() so that you can access the props in that.

Comment: You can see the solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406468/undefined-is-not-an-objectevaluating-this2-props-navigation-navigate-alert/55406737#55406737

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the issue, but worse case you can just put the variable in the upper scope.

```
showAlert() {
    const {navigation, position} = this.props
    Alert.alert(
```

Also I prefer not to bind and use the new syntax for creating class fields, you always get the right this.

```
showAlert = () => {
    ...
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showAlert}>
```